# Java, What is the difference between assigning null to object and just declaration

Tags: java, null, declaration

What is difference between :

- `Object o = null`;  and
- `Object o;` (just declaration)

Can anyone please answer me?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It depends on the scope where you declare the variable. For instance,  **local variables** don't have `default values` in which case you will have to assign **null** manually, where as in case of **instance variables** assigning null is redundant since instance variables get default values.

```
public class Test {
    Object propertyObj1;
    Object propertyObj2 = null; // assigning null is redundant here as instance vars get default values 

    public void method() {
        Object localVariableObj1;
        localVariableObj1.getClass(); // illegal, a compiler error comes up as local vars don't get default values

        Object localVariableObj2 = null;
        localVariableObj2.getClass(); // no compiler error as localVariableObj2 has been set to null

        propertyObj1.getClass(); // no compiler error
        propertyObj2.getClass(); // no compiler error
    }
}
```

Comment: could u pls fix the code tho? `Object localVariableObj1.getClass();` is invalid.. Same with `Object localVariableObj2.getClass();`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, object reference as `instance variable` need not be assigned `null` as those take `null` as default value. But local variables must be initialized otherwise you will get compilation error saying `The local variable s may not have been initialized`.

For more details you can refer [this link](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-1998/jw-03-initialization.html?page=2)